# Progress bar for download with VBA and WinHttpRequest

Tags: ms-access, vba, winhttp, winhttprequest

I have an Access 2010 database using the WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1 object to login into a server and then download Excel files that then get imported. The download of the files is painfully slow, so desperately need a progress bar or similar. But cannot figure out how to monitor progress of download.

Have everything working perfectly (so would prefer to not change objects) until I start trying to monitor download. As far as I can tell I need to do the Send method with asynchronous argument  = TRUE but then lost.  Is it through OnResponseDataAvailable event? But how, is there a good example anywhere?

I am sure this must have been done endless times by others but I have spent hours trying to find a neat complete description in another post or other resource. Could anyone point me to a good example?

And doesn't need to be fancy progress bar. I.e. doesn't even need to say percentage complete. Would be happy if just updated showing kB downloaded so users know hasn't frozen.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Do you have any code sofar? post your existing code so we can suggest any improvements.. ideally the saving part after the http.send request